# Test Python Google Cloud Functions locally

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying out the Python3.7 runtime on Google Cloud Functions. I am able to deploy the functions and make them work once deployed, however, I can't seem to run the emulator to test them locally before I deploy.

Google's documentation is a little inconsistent where they tell you to install the google functions emulator here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/emulator

But over on Firebase they tell you to `npm install` firebase-admin, firebase-tools and firebase-functions.

All of the emulator documentation references examples written in JS, none in Python so I'm wondering if these emulator even run Python functions locally?

Thanks

Comment: I never use emulators. Running Cloud Functions code at your desktop is extremely easy. Emulating the entry point just requires Json data. This allows you full access to use your debuggers, editors, and plain old print statements, etc.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use the [Functions Framework for Python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-python) to run the function locally.

Given a function in a file named `main.py` like so:

```py
def my_function(request):
    return 'Hello World'
```

You can do:

```
$ pip install functions-framework
$ functions-framework --target my_function
```

Which will start a local development server at http://localhost:8080.

To invoke it locally for an HTTP function:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080
```

For a background function with non-binary data:

```
$ curl -d '{"data": {"hi": "there"}}' -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
http://localhost:8080
```

For a background function with binary data:

```
$ curl -d "@binary_file.file" -X POST \
-H "Ce-Type: true" \
-H "Ce-Specversion: true" \
-H "Ce-Source: true" \
-H "Ce-Id: true" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: it doesn't work if you try to emulate the path behaivours

Comment: @DavidMabodo can you go into more detail? What do you mean by "emulate the path behaviors"?

Comment: Hi dustin! My fault, on not explaining this properly. Plus not using flask as I should do. I was not using the os.environ["APPLICATION_ROOT"] nor url_for so all my paths were broken when using the shortcut. Sorry for the randomly set comment.

Comment: @DustinIngram, can you please give an example of a curl command to test a main(context, event) function? thanks a lot!

Comment: @Hsn Depends, what type of background event are you attempting to emulate?

Comment: a pub/sub message?  can i emulate that?

Comment: @Hsn I added some examples to my answer.

Comment: i m having this error "missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'" ,  i tried to put the json as "{"event":1},{"context":1}".. what is the right format for pubsub?

Comment: Have you written an HTTP function with a single `request` argument, or a background function with two arguments, `event` and `context`?

Comment: its with two arguments, event and context like this def main(event, context):

Comment: @Hsn Try the "For a background function with non-binary data" example above. The value of `data` that you provide as the JSON request body eventually becomes the `event` argument, the `context` argument is created by the framework.

Comment: Anyone try to use this with the pubsub emulator as well?

Comment: What if I need to host multiple functions, to test functionality of one calling another? Does the second one end up at localhost:8081 or something?

Comment: @PavelKomarov Not by default, but see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-python/tree/master/examples/skaffold for an example of developing multiple functions on the same host

Comment: I think rather than using a separate library, I can just be careful to specify `--port` for my two servers. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/running/function-frameworks

Comment: Now I have a dilemma where I need to mock a `retrieve_data()` call inside my function, but I don't think I can do this in a locally deployed version. Can I? Is there a way to mock with `functions_framework`?

Answer (score 13):

## Update

Please, use the official emulator and serving framework from GCP https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-python

You can install it with

```
pip install functions-framework
```

---

## Deprecated

Based on Dustin's answer I've developed a package to serve as emulator:

```
pip install gcp-functions-emulator
```

Given you want to serve the following function

```
# mycloudfunction.py
def api(request):
  return 'important data'
```

To emulate we have to call it like so:

```
gcpfemu <path/to/file.py> <function_name>
```

For example, with the code above we will call it:

```
gcpfemu mycloudfunction.py api
```

And to access the data we can use for example curl:

```
curl localhost:5000/api
> important data
```

Comment: Could you provide the Github project link? This is a kind of project I'd like to contribute in.

Comment: @SayanSil https://gitlab.com/divisadero/cloud-functions-python-emulator

Comment: That's right @SurajSubramanian. However I recommend to use the official Google Functions Emulator instead of this one. Divisadero no longer maintains this pre-google-emulator one

Comment: Sure @dinigo, I'll try using the official emulator. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

See this project on GitHub: [GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework)

Currently there are only implementations in [Node.js](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs), [Go](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-go), and [PHP](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-php), but see [Issue #5](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework/issues/5) about the Python implementation.

I suggest, whatever implementation you use, to follow the [Functions Framework Contract](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework/blob/master/README.md)

> **UPDATE:** As Dustin mentioned, there is also a [Python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-python) implementation now.

Comment: The [Functions Framework for Python](https://pypi.org/project/functions-framework/) now exists, and I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

To run it in IntelliJ with `Target Type = Script Path` and the default options it should look like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return hello_get(request)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('127.0.0.1', debug=True)
```