# Debug locally a google cloud function written in python with storage trigger

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a google cloud function written in python which i would like to debug locally.
My function is triggered by an addition to a storage bucket and it performs some algorithm on the file uploaded to the bucket.
There are videos and instructions demonstrating this ability (local debug with breakpoints) for cloud functions written in Node.
So far i have not found any equivalent for python functions.
Is this possible? Any link explaining how to setup VScode or any other IDE to do that?

Comment: Have you tried [Functions Framework for Python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-python)  as suggested to this similar [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53693987/test-python-google-cloud-functions-locally)?

Answer (score 1):

You do know that there exists a `Cloud Functions Emulator` ( read about it here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/running/functions-emulator). It works both for Gen1 and Gen2 Cloud functions. Just put breakpoints in you code in `VS Code` and test the function.

Here is how you can test it locally:

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Attach to Cloud Functions",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5678, ## Select your port
            "host": "localhost",
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}", ## The folder your code is in
                    "remoteRoot": "/srv"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```